# mcpi.minecraft не подключается к minecraft-серверу

Tags: python, linux, сервер

Всем здравствуйте. Поднял сервер на майнкрафте на локалхосте, порт 4711. Замечательно работает, однако, есть проблемы с работой python3 на сервере.

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
```

Так понимаю, что Minecraft.create() занимается непосредственно подключением к серверу, поскольку ошибка такова:

```
>>> Minecraft.create()
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mcpi/minecraft.py", line 205, in create return Minecraft(Connection(address, port)) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mcpi/connection.py", line 17, in __init__ self.socket.connect((address, port)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Пробовал также писать Minecraft.create(localhost, 4711), Minecraft.create(127.0.0.1, 4711) и еще несколько вариантов, но без толку.

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь и объяснить, в чём же проблема?

Операционная система - Manjaro Linux. Порт 4711 - открытый.

Comment: Варианты `Minecraft.create(localhost, 4711), Minecraft.create(127.0.0.1, 4711)` разве не вызовут ошибки при выполнении? Да и если посмотреть в реализации `create`, то там уже указаны адреса и порт: https://github.com/martinohanlon/mcpi/blob/2e8112af6389563e645509b2690dd45000f1c907/mcpi/minecraft.py#L204 . Сервер точно слушает локалхост, а не `0.0.0.0` (т.е. внешнее подключение)?

Comment: Хм... да, я извиняюсь за свою глупость. Почитав логи, которые выдаёт скрипт при поднятии майнкрафт-сервера, я узнал, что сервер работает на *.25565. Что означает звёздочка, не подскажешь? Почему при подключении к серверу работает как подключение к 127.0.0.1, так и к 0.0.0.0?

И как к этому подключить mcpi? :)

Answer (score 2):

Сервер по умолчанию слушает порт 25565 (смотрим лог сервера).
Если изменить в Python-коде подключение на этот порт:

```
Minecraft.create("localhost", 25565)
```

то код исполнится без ошибок, НО! обмена с сервером **НЕ БУДЕТ**!

Нужно установить порт в настройках сервера (файл `server.propertis`) параметр

```
query.port=4711.
```

и тогда mcpi будет нормально работать с сервером с параметрами по умолчанию:

```
Minecraft.create()
```

Answer (score 1):

проблема возникает из-за отсутствия настроек подключения к базе sqlite в файле bukkit.yml
В моем случаи он должен выглядеть вот так и все  заработало:

```
settings:
  minimum-api: none
  allow-end: true
  warn-on-overload: true
  permissions-file: permissions.yml
  update-folder: update
  plugin-profiling: false
  connection-throttle: 4000
  query-plugins: true
  deprecated-verbose: default
  shutdown-message: Server closed
spawn-limits:
  monsters: 70
  animals: 15
  water-animals: 5
  ambient: 15
chunk-gc:
  period-in-ticks: 600
  load-threshold: 0
ticks-per:
  water-spawns: 1
  ambient-spawns: 1
  animal-spawns: 400
  monster-spawns: 1
  autosave: 6000
aliases: now-in-commands.yml
database:
  username: bukkit
  isolation: SERIALIZABLE
  driver: org.sqlite.JDBC
  password: walrus
  url: jdbc:sqlite:{DIR}{NAME}.db
```